# How to generate a cylinder with several holes except by knife tool and Boolean methods

Tags: mesh, modifiers

With the help in Stcak Exchange, I have known how to generate a cylinder with a hole except by knife tool and boolean methods. But all these method can not be used to generate a cylinder with several holes just like below. so please give me some examples. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [video](https://vimeo.com/68844586)

Comment: There's no reason boolean operations can't do that...

Answer (score 8):

1. Create two inner circles
2. Extrude and scale a border around the inner circles
3. Bridge the inner circles together with two segments.  Note the number of edges in the perimeter of the resulting mesh.
4. Create an outer circle with a larger radius.  Use the same number vertices as the perimeter in step 3.  Extrude and scale a border.
5. Bridge the outer and inner circles together.
6. Extrude the whole mesh in Z-axis to create a cylinder.
7. Add supporting edge loops around hard edges.
8. Apply subdivision surface modifier and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Nice and clean. Good job!

Answer (score -1):

[Does this help at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz-6rxgosjw)? You would start with a circle instead of a cylinder, but you can then just extrude it to your desired size and it will be a cylinder.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does this answer. Please include some of the details of this answer within the answer body itself.